# Argmax function of Tensorflow does not print value when evaluated on a constant tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new at Tensorflow. I am having a litte trouble at understanding its constants. I have this simple code mentioned below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
vector = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,1,2]],tf.int32,name="vector")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    v = sess.run(vector)
    argm = tf.argmax(v,1)
    print(argm)
```

I expect this to return something like `[4,7,8]`, as I understood from the documentation. Instead, I get this:

```
 Tensor("ArgMax:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int64).
```

So, i don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the answer of @James, you might want to use tensorflow's [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager), which behaves more like "standard" python: operations are executed as you type them, no more graphs and `Session`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

vector = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,1,2]],tf.int32,name="vector")
argm = tf.argmax(vector,1)
print(argm)
```

Comment: Learned something new, ty!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow operations like `tf.argmax` somewhat unintuitively don't perform the operation that they're stating, but add an operation to a graph that will be performed. When you run `argm = tf.argmax(v,1)`, the return value is tensor that isn't evaluated yet.

If you want the result of the argmax operation, you can run something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
vector = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,1,2]],tf.int32,name="vector")
argm = tf.argmax(vector,1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = sess.run(argm)
    print(a)
```

With this code, we're explicitly asking Tensorflow to run the computations to compute the result of the tf.argmax operation. With your previous code, we ran the computation to compute v (which is a constant, so that's pretty quick), then define a new graph operation to compute argmax on that - but never actually do the computation.